# C# Enum question automatic casting == Explicit enumeration conversion?

Tags: c#, enums, casting, enumeration, explicit

I'm a bit confused with the Explicit enumeration conversions what does that really mean..

I'm trying to use a Enumeration to do a pretty cool expected behavior and act as a nice magic number replacement at the same time.. kill two bird with one stone.

I got something like this.

```
public enum Size {Bare, Fixed, VariableByte, VariableShort};
```

The beauty in the expected behavior is in this protocol i'm working with.

If I just send a packet without any opcode command it's called a Bare packet meaning the buffer size is just payload similar to

> new byte[payloadSize]; but [payloadSize+Bare] would be equivalent

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[payloadSize+Bare];   //Bare = 0
```

If the packet is Fixed.. it contains a OpCode which has to be appended in front. so it's

> new byte[1+payload];

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[payloadSize+Fixed] //Fixed of course = 1.
```

VariableByte contains a opcode in front and a byte to represent the size of the packet. This is for packets in the 255 size range etc.. which is

> new byte[2+payload];

VariableShort is same as above except the packet size can be a word 65535 payload. which is

I may be causing myself problems in the future if the protocol ever changes then I may have to assign values to the enum in the future to fix problems but for now it's a valid enum which starts at index=0 [after googling I heard that if you don't start a enum at the default value of 0] it's not a correct valid enum.. lol idk what that means.. probably puts stress on enum operation.

Anyways back to my question.

as I already know I can do such as

```
int Ret = (int)Size.Bare;
```

or

```
int Ret = Convert.ToInt32(Size.Bare);
byte[] packet = new byte[payloadSize+Ret]
```

or best.

```
byte[] packet = new byte[payloadSize+(int)Size.Bare]
```

I'm trying to avoid as much amount of lines of coding as possible maybe even increase performance.

I was reading MSDN and found you can do this.. I haven't really discovered it's purpose but I am predicting what it may mean..

```
public enum Size : int {Bare, Fixed, VariableByte, VariableShort};
```

I assume this would be possible

```
byte[] packet = new byte[payloadSize+Size.Fixed];

byte[] packet = new byte[payloadSize+Size.VariableShort];
```

etc...

But unfortunately it isn't and I get this old error

**Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and Packet.Size**

so I wonder what does it really mean to put a byte casting in front of a Enum?
As it really doesn't make me do any cool things like I attempted above.

Does it just limit it to be casted to **byte** only? or something or it's plain old just for looks?

Doesn't seem to limit anything.

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[payloadZie+(byte)Size.Fixed];
```

Still works and of course **int != byte**.

Just wondering whats this could mean.
Thanks sorry if I ask too much questions :\
You guys provide better answers then any forum period.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/577946/can-i-avoid-casting-an-enum-value-when-i-try-to-use-or-return-it

Comment: good answer George but is static class same speed as enum? i wouldn't care about that little (int) if speed is faster for enum

Comment: I'd be surprised if using a static class wasn't slower, although the compiler might do something clever.

Comment: yah.. I was battling the urge to stay away from classes until chrfins answer which confirmed my assumption.. i will lose my method/function's little parameter that says Size size lol and resort to using int Size, ehh not big deal.. but screw it enums it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An enum provides for the switch statements and comparisons where you are comparing logical states or values.  (i.e ConnectionState == Connected vs ConnectionState == 1).

What you want here are integer values.  You can however write a class with public fields and/or properties to do what you want.  Make it static and you will provide the compiler/CLR with a good optimisation as well.

```
public static class Sizes
{
    public static readonly int Bare = 0;
    public static readonly int VariableByte = 65536;
}
```

You can use them the same way but now as Sizes.Bare is an integer with value 0 you can use it in an addition.

Comment: ya.. seen this in George's Link.. but is static class same speed as that enum? i really wouldn't care to use that (int) in front of a enum as long as performance is great. Plus this eliminates the need for a switch/if statements

Comment: Micro optimisation.  Enums infer state, what you want is something that explicitly represents the value 0, 4, 8 or 65536.  The (int)Enum infers a type check and cast for every use.  This should technically be faster (in debug code).  But refer to "micro optimisation" above.  A single IO call will remove any benefit from optimising a cast...

Comment: ya.. why on earth must I cast it. pfft.. btw i never really have to store the 65536 it's just how the protocol works if packet is that big  which increases the size to use 2 bytes so it's really 2 bytes + 1 opcode byte = 3.. so  thats why enum auto count 0,1,2,3 works. they shouldn't really do any cast operator if I cast the enum to int.. why does it :\

Comment: because enums are types.  They give you type safety, but type1 != type2 unless you write the implicit cast.

Comment: You could also just use public const int Bare = 0; etc.

Answer (score 1):

By default each value of an enum is of the type `int` and the first element starts with 0 and counting up by on on each element (or if you define the `[Flags]`-Attribute up by 2^n). If you creat an enum with `enum Size : byte` each element will be of the type `byte` and not int which is still explicid castable to `int`, but limited to 256 elements in total as you have only "one byte of numbers" available. So if you want to use the enum as the "paket size" an `int` enum is the better choice.

A big advantage of enums over a class with static `int` properties is that you can define the enum e.g. as a parameter type of a method parameter and then be shure you get a valid number, but if you use static `int`s you can define parameters only as `int` as well and so you need to check the parameter if it is valid every time.

Comment: yes yes..... completely forgot.. using int in the methods where I declared the enum as a parameter will look ugly if I use a class.. so I have to stick to enum.

Answer (score 0):

Specifying a type in the enum declaration only makes it use that type for the storage of the enum values, it doesn't change the syntax when you use the enum values.

The default storage type is `int`, so specifying that the enum should use `int` doesn't change anything, but it can still be useful to clarify that you specifically want to use that type.

---

If you are going to use the numeric values of the enums, you should specify them in the definition, and not rely on the default. That way it's clear from reading the code that you need them to have specific values:

```
public enum Size {
  Bare = 0,
  Fixed = 1,
  VariableByte = 2,
  VariableShort = 3
};
```