# why must I recast an enum parameter to its declared type?

Tags: c#, casting, enums

I have an enum defined as a short, however when passing one of the elements as a parameter, the computer refuses to accept that the enum is *already* a short and makes me recast it. My question is why?

i.e. enum settings : short {val1,val2,val3};

```
public void function (short param) 
{
    // ...
}

function(settings.val1); // will not compile

function((short)settings.val1); // will parse.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/577946/can-i-avoid-casting-an-enum-value-when-i-try-to-use-or-return-it

Answer (score 1):

Because settings.val1 is settings type not short and it doesn't support implicit cast. Enum : short just says that its fields are stored in short type memory area. Default type for Enum items is Int32

Answer (score 1):

You have an enum type named `settings`.  That enum's backing type happens to be `short`, but the type as far as the compiler is concerned is still `settings`.

Since `settings` has no implicit cast to `short`, an explicit one is required.

Comment: Thanks Philip and everyone who answered this question. This has given me a much better understanding of exactly how enum works - as a 'pseudo' type.

Answer (score 1):

Modify your method call to `public void function (settings param) { }`

Answer (score 1):

In this context, `:` is not an inheritance operator. Instead it just defines the backing data type. It's unfortunate that it looks like inheritance.