# Why must I use an explicit cast when using an enum in place of its underlying type?

Tags: c#, types, enums, casting, byte

```
public enum Foo : byte 
{
    BAR = 0x00,
    BAZ = 0x01,
    DERP = 0xFF
}

public void AppendAsHex(StringBuilder sb, byte b)
{
    sb.AppendFormat("{0:X}", b);
}
```

Why does this demand an explicit cast?

```
Foo theDerp = Foo.DERP;
AppendAsHex(sb, (byte)theDerp); // Fine
AppendAsHex(sb, theDerp); // Compile Error
```

No loss of precision can occur.  The method declares it only wants a `byte`, disregarding any `enum` goodness.

### EDIT

This works fine if we trade the `enum` for a `byte` and make the function take another numeric type, eg:

```
public void AppendAsHex(StringBuilder sb, uint u)
{
    sb.AppendFormat("{0:X}", u);
}

byte b = 21;

AppendAsHex(sb, b); // Fine
```

So, the compiler will promote a numeric type to a larger numeric type without any fuss, but demands a cast to do the same with an `enum:byte` to `byte`.

Clearly an `enum:byte` is not technically of *Type* `byte`, but surely the compiler could see it's of type `System.Enum` and check the type of the values contained in the `enum`?

While it makes perfect sense if using complex types the compiler may not be able to size up, in this case the compiler is fully aware of everything. I don't see how, if primitives can be promoted, the compiler would refuse to promote/cast something explicitly declared as a primitive.

It seems inconsistent to me and I'd like to understand it better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very simply because C# is strongly typed. An enum value is not of type byte even if you set it's translated values as byte, so you must cast it as byte before you can use it with a function that is expecting type byte. It's no different than casting another type.

Also, if your focus is on keeping things clean, you could consider rewriting (or overloading) your method slightly so that the cast is invisible to everything outside of it. It doesn't change the solution, but assuming you will be reusing the method in more than one place, it is less code:

```
public void AppendAsHex(StringBuilder sb, Foo b)
{
    AppendAsHex(sb, (byte)b);
}
public void AppendAsHex(StringBuilder sb, byte b)
{
    sb.AppendFormat("{0:X}", b);
}
```

At which point, this would work

```
Foo theDerp = Foo.DERP;
AppendAsHex(sb, theDerp);
```

Comment: Thanks, I do understand that... and it makes perfect sense if using complex types the compiler doesn't know about... but in this case, the compiler is fully aware of everything.  I don't see how, if primitives can be promoted, the compiler would refuse to promote/cast something explicitly declared as a primitive.

Comment: I think this is an active decision by the .NET to help guide people. If the signature requires a int/byte and I try to shove an Enum in, I would want it pointing out that this is not valid. However giving me to opportunity to cast it allows me to explicitly say I know what i am doing. Not all Enums represent numeric values (all though they may be backed by a numeric identifier), just like a phone number is can be a number but shouldn't be treated as having the properties of a number (add, subtract, order).

Comment: I would only want it "pointing out that this is not valid" if the underlying type of the enum was different.  What's the benefit of being able to specify the underlying type of an enum if you can't use its values in that way?  I hate muddying my code with (what I feel are) unnecessary casts.

Comment: I don't disagree with how you feel about it, but it's not going to change how it works.

Comment: @AlexMcMillan I added a little extra to the answer for an alternate way to write the code so that when you reuse the method you don't have to cast every time. Doesn't change the answer, but something to consider.

Comment: @LawrenceJohnson thanks.  It was actually the overloads that prompted me to ask this question.  I actually want to pass my function any of a bunch of numeric types (as well as `enum`s based on numeric types).  I hoped to just define my function as accepting the largest type and have everything implicitly cast/promote to that type, but the `enum`s wouldn't.

Comment: Whenever I write code that references a lot of enums, I also detest the way I have to cast them. In those cases I create a readonly struct of named integer constants that performs the same task without the casting. Far less annoying...

Answer (score 2):

> The underlying type specifies how much storage is allocated for each
>   enumerator. However, an explicit cast is necessary to convert from
>   enum type to an integral type.
>
> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032(v=vs.140).aspx

So, despite the use of `:` to declare the underlying type, the actual base type of any enum is `System.Enum`. That's why it still needs explicit cast.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757684/enum-inheritance).

An enum cannot inherit from anything but System.Enum so all the ': byte' is doing is changing how the values of an enum are represented.

Comment: What has inheritance got to do with it?  Why can't the compiler look up the underlying type, realise it's the exact type expected, and perform the cast?  Is there some downside like accidentally passing a `byte` when you meant to pass a `byte`?  That just doesn't make sense.

Comment: From [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/577946/can-i-avoid-casting-an-enum-value-when-i-try-to-use-or-return-it/577953#577953) it's per the spec. i.e. by design. You can find the spec [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-334.htm). We can only guess as for the reasons behind the design.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I wish there was a logical reason for it.

Comment: The oddest thing is this "Foo theDerp = Foo.DERP;" What does that mean? How can you assign a value of enum to the enum itself?